unable to run start_notebook_execution for an EMR Jupyter notebook
Why is my AWS EMR Jupyter notebook saying that my cluster id is null? I've verified that 1) the cluster id value being passed is neither null, None, nor '' (empty string) and 2) confirmed that the cluster in question is running (I'm actually running this from a notebook that is on that cluster). How can I work past this and/or debug this? Details are below.
When I try calling start_notebook_execution as described in the boto3 documentation, I am getting the following error:
An error was encountered:
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the StartNotebookExecution operation: The EMR cluster Id null is not available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 553, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1009, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the StartNotebookExecution operation: The EMR cluster Id null is not available

This exact same code has worked for other clusters and notebooks, so it's highly unlikely that the problem is in the code itself (not shown). I assume there is something wrong with my IAM role permissions. For the cluster/notebook where I'm now having this issue, I originally got the errors below. After adding the following policy/permissions to address those errors, I got the error above.
Previous errors:
An error was encountered:
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartNotebookExecution operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/EMR_EC2_DefaultRole/i-<roleid> is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<account>:role/EMR_Notebooks_DefaultRole because no identity-based policy allows the iam:PassRole action
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 553, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1009, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartNotebookExecution operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/EMR_EC2_DefaultRole/i-<roleid> is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<account>:role/EMR_Notebooks_DefaultRole because no identity-based policy allows the iam:PassRole action

An error was encountered:
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartNotebookExecution operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/EMR_EC2_DefaultRole/i-<roleid> is not authorized to perform: elasticmapreduce:StartNotebookExecution on resource: arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:us-east-1:<account>:notebook-execution/* because no identity-based policy allows the elasticmapreduce:StartNotebookExecution action
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 553, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1009, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartNotebookExecution operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/EMR_EC2_DefaultRole/i-<roleid> is not authorized to perform: elasticmapreduce:StartNotebookExecution on resource: arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:us-east-1:<account>:notebook-execution/* because no identity-based policy allows the elasticmapreduce:StartNotebookExecution action


An error was encountered:
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartNotebookExecution operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/EMR_EC2_DefaultRole/i-<roleid> is not authorized to perform: elasticmapreduce:StartNotebookExecution on resource: arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:us-east-1:<account>:editor/e-<editor> because no identity-based policy allows the elasticmapreduce:StartNotebookExecution action
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 553, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1009, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartNotebookExecution operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/EMR_EC2_DefaultRole/i-<roleid> is not authorized to perform: elasticmapreduce:StartNotebookExecution on resource: arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:us-east-1:<account>:editor/e-<editor> because no identity-based policy allows the elasticmapreduce:StartNotebookExecution action

inline policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "elasticmapreduce:StartNotebookExecution",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:<region>:<account>:editor/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:<region>:<account>:notebook-execution/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<account>:role/EMR_Notebooks_DefaultRole"
        }
    ]
}


It turns out this was happening because I wasn't using the correct region for the client. I'm leaving this post up in case anyone else stumbles on this error, since the cause is so non-obvious.
